# Building the Flutter app apk in release mode, a portion of code shows grey screen in some devices. Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance

Tags: android, flutter, user-interface, responsive-design

The code with a horizontal listview appears grey screen on some real devices after installing apk. Works fine in emulator but issue in actual devices. I have commented the portion of code causing the issue.
This is the full code-

WillPopScope(
onWillPop: onWillPop,
child: SafeArea(
child: Scaffold(

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage(
              'assets/images/ShortLogo.jpeg',
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        title: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "Morning",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: _width * 0.04,
              ),
            ),
            Text(
              " ${name} !",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: _width * 0.04,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ],
        ),

  
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,

        actions: [
         
          IconButton(
            icon: ImageIcon(
              AssetImage('assets/images/icons/Notification.png'),
              color: Colors.black,
            ),
            onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/notification'),
          ),
        
          Builder(
              builder: (context) => IconButton(
                    icon: ImageIcon(
                      AssetImage('assets/images/icons/menu.png'),
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    splashColor: primaryColor,
                    onPressed: () => Scaffold.of(context).openEndDrawer(),
                  )),
        ],
      ),
      endDrawer: CustomDrawer(),
      //   drawer: CustomDrawer(),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: _height * 0.01, horizontal: _width * 0.02),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
             
             
              Obx(() {
                if (productCategoryController.isLoading())
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                return Container(
                  height: _height * .3, //.4
                  width: double.infinity,
                  child: CarouselSlider.builder(
                    itemCount: productCategoryController.bannerList.length,
                    options: CarouselOptions(
                      autoPlay: true,
                      enlargeCenterPage: true,
                      viewportFraction: 1,

                
                      initialPage: 0,
                      onPageChanged: (index, reason) =>
                          setState(() => currentImage = index),
                    ),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index, realIndex) {
                      return Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),

                            ///10
                            image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                              image: NetworkImage(productCategoryController
                                  .bannerList[index]
                                  .toString()),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.grey[100],
                          ),
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 5, horizontal: 5)
                        
                          );
                    },
                  ),
                );
              }),
        
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(.0),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: 'topUpButton',
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: yellow,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                                onPressed: () => Get.to(RechargeTab1()),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    ImageIcon(AssetImage(
                                      "assets/images/icons/TopUp.png",
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(width: _width * 0.04),
                                    Text(
                                      'Top-Up',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: _width * 0.04),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                minHeight: 50, maxHeight: 50),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: green,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white),
                         
                              onPressed: () async {
                                showLoaderDialog(context);
                                await productCategoryController
                                    .getCategories();

                                Get.back();
                                Get.to(ProductCategoriesScreen());
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  ImageIcon(AssetImage(
                                    "assets/images/icons/store.png",
                                  )),
                                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                                  Text(
                                    'Store',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontSize: _width * 0.04),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Hero(
                            tag: 'donationButton',
                            child: ConstrainedBox(
                              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                  maxHeight: 50, minHeight: 50),
                              child: ElevatedButton(
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: blue,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                              
                                onPressed: () => Get.toNamed('/donate'),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    ImageIcon(AssetImage(
                                      "assets/images/icons/onate.png",
                                    )),
                                    SizedBox(width: 10),
                                    Text(
                                      'Donation',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                          fontSize: _width * 0.04),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(width: 20),
                        Expanded(
                          child: ConstrainedBox(
                            constraints: BoxConstraints(
                                maxHeight: 50, minHeight: 50),
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                                  backgroundColor: red,
                                  foregroundColor: Colors.white),
                  
                              onPressed: () async {
                                Get.toNamed('/event');
                              },
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: [
                                  ImageIcon(AssetImage(
                                    "assets/images/icons/event.png",
                                  )),
                                  SizedBox(width: 10),
                                  Text(
                                    'Event',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                        fontSize: _width * 0.04),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),

              

              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 20.0,
                ),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      "Top Products",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: _width * 0.06),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                        onPressed: () async {
                          showLoaderDialog(context);
                          await productCategoryController.getCategories();

                          Get.back();
                          Get.to(ProductCategoriesScreen());
                          //Get.to(ProductCategoriesScreen());
                        },
                        child: Text(
                          "View More",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: _width * 0.035,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

**// the listview below is the part causing issue**

```
              productCategoryController.isLoading()
                  ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                  : SizedBox(
                      height: _height * 0.27,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        itemCount: topProductsLength,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () {
                              newProductController.product =
                                  productCategoryController
                                      .topProducts[index];

                              Get.to(() => TopProductDetailScreen());
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(_width * 0.02),
                              child: Container(
                                width: _height * 0.2,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                                child: Column(
                                  //  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                                        child: Container(
                                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            color: prideGrey,
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(8),

                                            image: DecorationImage(
                                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                              image: NetworkImage(
                                                  "
                                                      productCategoryController
                                                          .topProducts[
                                                              index]
                                                          .imageUrl"),
                                            ),
                                       
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: _width * 0.03,
                                          vertical: _width * 0.01),
                                      child: Row(
                                        mainAxisAlignment:
                                            MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                        children: [
                                          Text(
                                            productCategoryController
                                                .topProducts[index]
                                                .productName
                                                .replaceRange(
                                                    8,
                                                    productCategoryController
                                                        .topProducts[index]
                                                        .productName
                                                        .length,
                                                    '...'),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                overflow:
                                                    TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                color: Colors.black,
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                fontSize: _width * 0.035),
                                          ),
                                          Text(
                                              "\$${productCategoryController.topProducts[index].currentPrice.toInt().toString()}",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: prideBlue,
                                                  fontWeight:
                                                      FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize:
                                                      _width * 0.035)),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                          EdgeInsets.all(_height * 0.01),
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 28,
                                        child: ElevatedButton(
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                minimumSize: Size(
                                                    double.infinity, 28),
                                                textStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize:
                                                        _width * 0.03),
                                                backgroundColor:
                                                    Color(0xffBF0A30)),
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              newProductController.product =
                                                  productCategoryController
                                                      .topProducts[index];

                                        

                                              Get.to(() =>
                                                  TopProductDetailScreen());
                                            },
                                            child: Text("View Details")),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    )
        
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```